# Adding custom data for an operation to Application Insights telemetry

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to add a bunch of custom data fields to every piece of telemetry I can, and this data is consistent across a single operation, but varies from operation to operation.
I have a custom ITelemetryInitializer, and within that I can do something like:

```
public class MyInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
            telemetry.Context.Properties[ "platform" ] = "PC";
    }
}
```

But I don't understand how I'm suppose to push this data into this initializer.

I've added something like this:

```
public class MyInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private string mPlatform = "unknown";

    public void Initialize(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
            telemetry.Context.Properties[ "platform" ] = mPlatform;
    }

    public void SetPlatform(string platform)
    {
       mPlatform = platform
    }
}
```

And then at the controller level I do something like this:

```
foreach (var init in TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers)
{
   var customInit = init as MyInitializer;

   if (customInit != null)
   {
      customInit.SetPlatform(requestPlatform);
   }
}
```

But this is horribly clunky, and prone to error (e.g. if a piece of telemetry gets sent before this function is called), and I'm not really sure if this is thread-safe.

What's the intended way of passing around this kind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved this now, the solution is to write to the properties of the TelemetryClient within the controller like this:

```
[Route( "[controller]" )]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient        mTelemetryClient;

    public MyController( 
        TelemetryClient             TelemetryClientArg )
    {
        mTelemetryClient = TelemetryClientArg;
        mTelemetryClient.Context.Properties.Remove("platform");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Produces( "application/json" )]
    public IActionResult Post( [FromBody] RequestClass RequestData )
    {
       mTelemetryClient.TrackTrace("Test trace 1"); // doesn't have platform set
       mTelemetryClient.Context.Properties["platform"] = RequestData.platform;
       mTelemetryClient.TrackTrace("Test trace 2"); // has platform set correctly
    }
 }
```

This seems to be safe as the controller constructor appears to be called before each http request is processed and the context within the TelemetryClient is unique per thread. I would like to get confirmation from the team that this is reasonable.